# Overriding CSS classes

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9, jQuery 1.6.2 and jQuery UI. I would like to override some CSS `class` attributes for my [tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) *without* change the original CSS file generated by the [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/).

How can I do that? What do you advice about?

P.S.: I would like to style my tabs without modifying the jQuery UI CSS file at all so that, in future developments, I can "re-generate" that file without lose my custom CSS statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite simple to achieve. CSS applies styling based on load order. To override any style, it needs to be loaded after the core stylesheet.

1. Load your jQuery UI CSS.
2. Load your custom CSS file.

In your custom CSS file, you can override your tab structure using the same markup found in the core UI CSS file.

This will allow you to re-generate and replace the core files without losing your customization.

Answer (score 1):

A simple thing would be to create a secondary stylesheet.

Include the same styles for the tabs in this secondary sheet.

Place it under the Themeroller CSS in the head.

Because the styles are "last" in order, they will be applied without changing the original styles.

Comment: You are right, but it will be a "system constrain" (to remember for the days to come!)...

Comment: Usually, I place my css style links and js links in an `include` and then reference that on each page.  In this way, you can remove or modify easily in the future.

Comment: @Backo: this is a very common approach, to make it clearer you could give your stylesheet an appropriate name, like `<original_stylesheet_name>_changes.css`. This way the order is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really general question. I'd say to use something like firebug in FF to figure out where the styles are coming from (especially useful when you are using jQuery UI; I find the CSS gets tricky). Then you've got to sort out scoping yourself, or give more details in your question.

Comment: What details do you need? - I only would like to know an approach, pratice or technique in order to don't change the original CSS file generated by the ThemeRoller. Nothing more.

Comment: @Backo Ah, well john's suggestion is good. Alternatively, you could use inline styles.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily. Lets say you want to override the color of any element in jquery.ui.css then you can do as below.

```
.myClass{
  color:red !important;//specify important to any style you want to override.
}
```

Comment: `!important` is a one-shot sledgehammer that is best avoided. Write a more specific selector instead.

Comment: Yes I agree to use to more specific selector but in certain cases its not possible to write the selector if the markup and css is coming from a plugin in that case overriding css using important only helps.

Comment: The only times that you can't (just) write a more specific selector are when the code already uses `!important` or uses inline style. `!important` should be treated as a last resort, not option number 1.

Answer (score 0):

yon use `.css`

```
$("#elemID").css({backgroundColor:'Red',text:'Blue'});
```

Comment: Is that to much effort to accomplish what I would like to do?

Comment: Imho yes, this is too much effort. There is no dynamics here, you just want to redefine css. I would go for the additional css-file.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery addclass() and removeclass() selectors.

Comment: As said to john, is that to much effort to accomplish what I would like to do?

Comment: He does not want to add or remove a clas, just redefine the css.

Comment: place common properties in a single class and the properties which need to be override can be placed in another class and use jquery addclass() to add that class on runtime.

Comment: these are only two statements 1. addclass("classname"), and 2. removeclass("classname"), there is no effort in them.