# How to prevent adding CSS 'class' properties

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9, jQuery 1.6.2 and jQuery UI. I am trying to implement nested tabs by following the [official documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/).

When I state the following (that is the "normal"\"common" way as stated in the documentation source code)

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li>...</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
</script>
```

and then I go to display the HTML code generated, jQuery UI automatically add the following CSS `class` properties to the `<div id="tabs">`:

```
<div class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="tabs">
  ...
</div>
```

**Is it possible to prevent adding some of those CSS `classes`? If so, how to do that?**

Comment: Why do you want to do that? It would probably stop the tabs from working.

Comment: It would be rather easy to remove the css code for ui tabs from its css file to accomplish what i think that youre trying to accomplish. ( though i think this question comes from that maybe being a bit slow process....? )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always `$("#tabs").removeClass("whatever")` if you want, but you'll likely lose certain functionality if you do.  The real question is why do you want to do this?

Comment: It is because I would like not to do the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816905/overriding-css-classes

Comment: In that case, don't bother removing the classes, just overwrite any styles applied to those classes (either in a page stylesheet, or in another external stylesheet as outlined in your other question).

EDIT - Sorry, just re-read your comment.  Why would you not like to do that?  That seems like the cleanest solution, with relatively little overhead compared to modifying the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the `CSS` effects that the tabs are giving, just remove the styles from the `CSS` document.

Answer (score 0):

I would override the styles on the pages where you don't want the effect. For example if  `ui-corner-all` has a property of `float:left` in the jquery UI style sheet and that style is interfering with your page. It would be best to have a class by the same name on the page you're working on to override the style. It would be less expensive than modifying the dom to remove classes.